# tomcat 6.0.35 Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. No suitable driver at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:243)

Tags: mysql, hibernate, tomcat, jdbc, c3p0

Apache Tomcat 6.0.35 Hibernate Problem

com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@352e71c4 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception: 
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:279)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is rising with Ubuntu 12.04.2. What u need to do is to change hibernate library. I change it from v 4.1.2 to 4.1.9 and it is working fine.